# Push data inside specific field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Can anyone tell me how I can push data inside group  ?

productSchema

```
    const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    user:[{ 
        author:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user'
        }
    }],
    group:[{
        group:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'group',
        item:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'item',
        }
    }
    }],
    price:{
        type:number
    },

});

productSchema.pre<IProduct>(/^find/, function(next) {
    this.populate({
          path: 'user.author',
          select: 'fullName email'
        });
        next();
      });

productSchema.pre<IProductSchema>(/^find/, function(next) {
    this.populate({
        path: 'group.group',
        select: '-__v'
        })
        next();
    });
 productSchema.pre<IProductSchema>(/^find/, function(next) {
        this.populate({
            path: 'group.group.item',
            select: '-__v -group'
        })
            next();
});
```

I successfully populate **group.group** but in **group.group.item** I`m not eaven able to push data, this is my push code.

```
        const updateProduct = await PRODUCT.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,  {
        $push: {
          group: { group: req.params.groupId}
        }
        }
    );
    const query = await Item.find().where(`group`).equals(req.params.groupId).select('-group id');
 query.forEach(async element => {
        const updateProduct = await PRODUCT.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,  {
            $push: {
                group: {"group.item": 'element._id'}}
            }
            
        );
    });
```

I spend last few hours trying to found solution but unfortunately I`m not able to found it. Hope someone will be able to help me.

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

based on the `$push` [documentation](http://The%20$push%20operator%20appends%20a%20specified%20value%20to%20an%20array)

> The $push operator appends a specified value to an array

in the schema item is a object just try like this if you want push a value

```
item:[{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'item',
}]
```

if you don't want to change the type of item to a `array` based on following code find the document with `_id` and `group._id` after that update the the item like this

```
await PRODUCT.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: req.params.id,
    'group._id': groupId,
  },
  {
    "group.$.item" : "the ID"
  }
);
```

if you changed type of item

```
await PRODUCT.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: req.params.id,
    'group._id': groupId,
  },
  {$push:{
    "group.$.item" : element._id
  }}
);
```

Comment: I change my schema but still not able to push it

Comment: do you want to push in parent group??

Comment: Yes that is what I want